# Terminal in Emacs in Windows - Error message: "Spawning child process; invalid argument"

Tags: windows, emacs

I'm trying to start a **cmd** terminal in Emacs 23.2 (latest version) in Windows.

According to the [Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Terminal-emulator.html#Terminal-emulator), I can enter in terminal mode (starting a new buffer for the terminal) in Emacs by typing `M-x term`.

When I do this, I get prompted for:

```
Run program: path_to-emacs/bin/cmdproxy.exe
```

When I type `RET`, I get the following error message in the minibuffer:

```
Spaning child process: invalid argument
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: I have the same issue here, but with 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash.exe' (Which is to say, the "use an actual shell" is unlikely to be the issue)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263012

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should do:

- <kbd>M-:</kbd>`(make-comint-in-buffer "cmd" nil "cmd" nil)`
- <kbd>M-x</kbd>eshell
- <kbd>M-x</kbd>shell

All have both their pros and cons. So choose what suits you best.

Comment: No. I have no idea why, but with «shell» MinGW's gdb have strange misbehavior. E.g. an application running under it do not prints a print statements, complaining about an invalid arguments when I enter something. The gdb runnning in a plain terminal have no a problems at all, so this is surely Emacs's issue. The same for both modes `gdb` and `gud-gdb`.

Comment: I found what th problem I had. Wrote it here it the hope it help someone: the Windows® terminal have it's own encoding(can be found with chcp command, it is could different, depends on locale), and in order to work with the gdb one need to set buffer's encoding to accord a system one

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error while trying to run `M-x compile`. I added the following to my `.emacs` file and it fixed the problem:

```
;; Make sure that the bash executable can be found
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "C:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe")
(setq shell-file-name explicit-shell-file-name)
(add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/cygwin/bin")
```

Obviously this solution will only work if you have Cygwin installed, but if you are running Emacs on Windows it is usually worth at least a minimal install of Cygwin because many Emacs commands can leverage the command-line tools made available by cygwin (`M-x compile` in my case).

Comment: The issue with this answer is that [Cygwin bash does not work in Emacs Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670209/cygwin-bash-does-not-display-correctly-in-emacs-shell)...

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem.

I ran procmon and discovered that Emacs wants to find `c:\bin\sh` in some form (`sh.exe`, `sh.bat`, `sh.cmd`, etc).
Since I happened to want to use term mode with the android debugging shell, I created `c:\bin\sh.bat` with contents "adb shell", and it worked fine, albeit with some weird input lag.

Comment: I looked into this a bit and term mode has some hard-coded paths to executables, so on Windows it looks in some awkward places.

Comment: @Dave can you include some links/instructions on what you did with procmon to trouble shoot the problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `term` or `ansi-term` with cmd.exe or Cygwin bash on Windows with Win32 Emacs you can, take a look at this project:

[fakecygpty](https://github.com/d5884/fakecygpty)

Works very nicely for me on Win 10.

Answer (score 2):

Try `M-x cmd-shell`instead. I suggest using [`EmacsW32`](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html) for the best results.

Comment: Thanks İsmail, I can surely use M-x shell in both Emacs and EmacsW32, and M-x cmd-shell in EmacsW32, but I would like to emulate an actual terminal to get some interactive console programs working properly. In other words, I would like to get M-x term working.

Comment: Then you need an actual shell like bash from cygwin or msys. cmd.exe from Windows is not a UNIXy shell.

Comment: I have msys bash, but (term "bash") or (term "the-full-path-to-bash.exe") both still complain of invalid argument.. ??

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this in my .bash_profile, you should be able to set this to whatever you need. Note - when I do this I need to re `source ~/.bash_profile` to get all of my aliases and stuff, which I still haven't figured out.

When I run Emacs by "clicking" a file to start Emacs - I get a Windows CMD line, when I launch from within cygwin - I get a cygwin type shell.

```sh
export ESHELL="c:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe"
```